# I can't get cross domain ajax working with Weblogic/Spring 3

Tags: java, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am having trouble trying to get cross-domain ajax request working and despite the many solutions I have found on Stack Overflow I am unable to get it working.

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'http://SERVER:PORT/CONTEXT/RESOURCE.html?someParameter=1234',
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(xhr) {
            alert('ok '+JSON.stringify(xhr));
        },
                error : function(xhr) {
                        alert('error '+JSON.stringify(xhr));
                }
    });
```

Doing just a standard $.ajax call with datatype "json" the server responds with a blank response and statusText "error", like so:

```
 error {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

So I tried simply changing datatype to "jsonp" as suggested in other threads but this time it still goes to error condition with the following response:

```
error {"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

and an error message of "parsererror"
Yet no data.

What gives?

Do I need to do something special on the server side because it is Spring MVC in Weblogic?

EDIT: 
jQuery version 1.9.1
Spring-3 MVC

EDIT2: Oh yes I also tried $.getJSON but this command seems to do nothing - when I run the code replacing $.ajax with $.getJSON nothing happens. No response and I dont see any error occurring in console and no Network request seen going to the URL. I did also change the syntax in a 2nd try where I called it like $.getJSON(url, callback); but that did not change anything

EDIT3: I should also mention when I run the original code using "json" datatype and look in Firebug's Response tab, it is empty. But when I run the second code using "jsonp" I do see the JSON text in the Response tab. So it is strange why it still throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, upon more research I finally found the cause - yes I did need to do something on the Server side to support jsonp. I ended up writing a servlet filter which wraps the returning json string in the appropriate callback.

Learn something new everyday!

```
public class JsonPCallbackFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JsonPCallbackFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //logger.debug("Filter: "+request.getRequestURI());

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String[]> parms = request.getParameterMap();

        if(parms.containsKey("callback")) {
            logger.debug("Wrapping response with JSONP callback '" + parms.get("callback")[0] + "'");

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            ByteResponseWrapper wrapper = new ByteResponseWrapper(response);

            chain.doFilter(request, wrapper);

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            sb.append(parms.get("callback")[0] + "(");
            sb.append(new String(wrapper.getBytes()));
            sb.append(new String(");"));

            out.write(sb.toString().getBytes());

            wrapper.setContentType("text/javascript;charset=UTF-8");
            response.setContentLength(sb.length());

            out.close();
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}

static class ByteOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
       bos.write(b);            
    }

    public byte[] getBytes() {
       return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}

static class ByteResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {
   private PrintWriter writer;
   private ByteOutputStream output;

   public byte[] getBytes() {
      writer.flush();
      return output.getBytes();
   }

   public ByteResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
      super(response);
      output = new ByteOutputStream();
      writer = new PrintWriter(output);
   }

@Override
public PrintWriter getWriter() {
    return writer;
}

@Override
public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
    return output;
   }
}

    <filter>
      <filter-name>jsonpFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.blahblah.JsonPCallbackFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>jsonpFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Great! All that for nothing. Found out I cannot get the session object when I do this, guess its cross domain cookie restriction. Back to the drawing board.